# Comparison not working Arduino

Tags: arduino, comparison, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

This is probably going to be a novice mistake, but I am totally at a loss on what to do.

I was trying to make a code to read a tweet based on a code I found on the internet, but found out Twitter changed their API and couldn't do it anymore.

What I'm trying to do is read a message and activate a pin from my Arduino to open a model garage.

So far I created a website on wix and my arduino is able to read it.

But the comparison to see if it fits into the first case isn't working at all, even though it is supposed to be the same as the previous print.

I used tweet.length() and it told me my string was 31 characters long, which means there aren't any hidden characters, right?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
boolean requested;                   // whether you've made a request since connecting
long lastAttemptTime = 0;            // last time you connected to the server, in milliseconds
boolean garage_status = false;
String currentLine = "";            // string to hold the text from server
String tweet = "";                  // string to hold the tweet
boolean readingTweet = false; 
// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
//IPAddress server(74,125,232,128);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
char server[] = "gusat92.wix.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(10,32,153,88);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server 
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
 pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
    currentLine.reserve(256);
  tweet.reserve(150);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /garage?_escaped_fragment_ HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: gusat92.wix.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } 
  else {
    // kf you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (client.connected()) {
    if (client.available()) {
      // read incoming bytes:
      char inChar = client.read();

      // add incoming byte to end of line:
      currentLine += inChar; 

      // if you get a newline, clear the line:
      if (inChar == '\n') {
        currentLine = "";
      } 
      // if the current line ends with <text>, it will
      // be followed by the tweet:
      if ( currentLine.endsWith("\"Text\">")) {
        // tweet is beginning. Clear the tweet string:
        readingTweet = true; 
        tweet = "";
      }
      // if you're currently reading the bytes of a tweet,
      // add them to the tweet String:
      if (readingTweet) {
        if (inChar != '&') {
          tweet += inChar;
        } 
        else {
          // if you got a "<" character,
          // you've reached the end of the tweet:
          readingTweet = false;
          Serial.println(tweet);
          Serial.println(tweet.length());
          if(tweet == "    <h2 class=\"font_2\">Opener"){//this part is never true
           digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
           delay(5000);
           Serial.println("LED ON!");
           garage_status=true;
           digitalWrite(2, LOW);
          }
          else {Serial.println("no out");}
          if(tweet != "    <h2 class=\"font_2\">Closer" && garage_status==true){
           digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
           delay(5000);
           Serial.println("LED OFF!");
           garage_status=false;
           digitalWrite(3, LOW);
          }

          // close the connection to the server:
          client.stop(); 
        }
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

This is what it prints>

```
connecting...
connected

>
    <h2 class="font_2">Opener
31
no out
```

The tweet part is exactly the same as the comparison, right? :S

Comment: You are comparing pointers and not strings and the pointers are never the same. With bare `char *` you would use `strcmp` to compare strings. Not sure if it is there on Arduino but I think there is a `String` class you could use.

Comment: Seems like that's the thing, tried using strcmp and it told me error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)' How can I change the pointer to a string? :S

Comment: just use a ctor? http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors

Comment: Or let's say I coded it in c++, what would I have to do to make the tweet variable a string?

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem you might be having is that the

> ```
>     <h2 class="font_2">Opener
> ```

contains a different white space than the one you are checking for. If the string contains a tab rather than a number of spaces and you are checking for the other one then you wont find a match.

One possibility to avoid this is to only look for the part that is of interest, i.e.

> ```
> <h2 class="font_2">Opener
> ```

You can do this using methods of the `String` class e.g. like this

```
  if( tweet.indexOf("<h2 class=\"font_2\">Opener") != -1 ) {
```

Let me know if this helps